How can I change system file values?
I had the original battery on my Redmi K20 Pro for like 5 years. The battery degraded quite a bit so I disconnected the original battery from the bms and attached an external battery on the back of my phone of 5000mah capacity and connected it to the bms. But the problem is the phone only charges the battery to around 3800mah and shows 100%. But after using it for a few mins its drops to ~75%
Now my phone has custom rom running and is rooted so I opened these system files using root explorer and there's this file named charge_full and charge_full_design. I tried changing these values with root explorer but I can't. how center image description herean I change these values to like 4900mah to correctly charge the battery to full?

This may help if the capacity is NOT hard coded in kernel

Have you tried SetEdit with permissions granted via ADB?  You can also try, e.g., X-plore set to SU mode.
